# 2 day waiting period for bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

Why is there a 2 day waiting period for placing a bounty on a question? I have had several questions that I have had that just don't get the exposure I'm looking for and they are time-sensitive questions. One of the easiest ways to increase exposure is to offer a bounty, but sometime I don't have 2 days to wait. And I don't often get the answers I need until the bounty has been offered.

I feel the waiting period should be dropped.

Comment: Related MSE discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat

Comment: On a more serious note, I think the delay exists as a fairness measure so that people unwilling (or unable) to offer bounties get visibility on their questions too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ultimately, the 2-day waiting period exists to level the paying field to some extent and a side benefit is it gives the community the ability to act on bad questions.

I am [all for reducing the bounty time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210384/its-time-to-remove-the-bounty-delay/210396#210396) on Stack Overflow and other high-volume sites, but eliminating it completely eliminating it just opens up a lot of issues.

- Quick bounties limit the ability of the community to close bad questions since a bounty prevents closure.  If users were allowed to place immediately bounties, they could theoretically offer a bounty just to prevent a question from getting closed.
- Immediate bounties would shift the site closer an auction site.  There is enough rep-whoring now, by permitting immediate bounties you might end up with "answers to the highest bidder" mentality.
- New users don't have rep to offer a bounty, and while the percentage of new users who ask good questions is low, you limit the ability of those users to get their questions noticed.

While all due respect for your timelines, if you **frequently** find yourself needing immediate answers to keep to your schedule,  then maybe you need to evaluate your schedule.  I realize emergencies come up, but when they come up often enough, maybe you need to look in the mirror first.

Comment: 1. Yes, someone may post a stupid question and offer a bounty for it. But thy the hack should they? Solving theoretical problems is good... in theory only. 2. Do you believe they'd so many bounties so that non-bounty questions would get unnoticed? Or is this just a theory? 3. It's perfectly enough when it happens once. The current policy is not preventing anyone from **frequently** offering an early bounty, it's preventing anyone from doing it **even once**.

Comment: We should give users with a higher level the ability to only wait a few hours or one day.