# Allow to add a bounty before first 2 days

Tags: feature-request

At the risk of being downvoted, I will like to give my  question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649938/avi-created-with-avistreamwrite-has-zero-length-duration more attention from the community.

The question seems to be bit too specific to be answered without a bounty. A bounty would help and  would be glad if some high rep users offer bounty or answers on my linked  question. Waiting for 2 days would be too late and I don't have enough reputation to offer bounty.

Comment: 1.  You don't have enough reputation to post a decent bounty.

Comment: 2.  You only asked the question 38 minutes ago.  Give the community some time to look at it.  That's part of the reason why there is a bounty delay.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on SO to meet your deadlines for you.

Comment: How can you know if the question is "too specific to be answered without a bounty" without first giving it a chance? The more specific a question is, the easier it is for people to answer.

Comment: In my humble opinion your question is in need of [heavy minimization](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) even before any bounties. Well, it is possible that the code in the question is already MCVE, but nonetheless, I'd tried to compress it a bit more.

Comment: Huge tip: When a mod edits the format of your post, it's typically for a good reason. That last paragraph doesn't need to be bolded, and @RobertHarvey was helping you by editing the bold out.

Comment: See also: [Why can't I just offer a bounty for a question right off the bat?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3330/262755)

Comment: @Fish Below the Ice Actually he and I were editing at the same time and I got confused.

Comment: @user2330678 Then no harm, no foul. Just a tip. You're definitely overusing bold in your SO question now, and there are people that will downvote based on that.

Comment: @user2330678 Also worth noting, while you can't put a bounty on the question for two days, you have brought attention to it through Meta, whether good or bad. So there's that as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind waiting 48 hours to offer a bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251739/what-is-the-reason-behind-waiting-48-hours-to-offer-a-bounty) and/or [2 day waiting period for bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255995/2-day-waiting-period-for-bounty)

Comment: Everyone else downvoted you to get the `downvote` badge despite this being a pretty reasonable meta question - SHAME. Shame on all of you. Take this upvote brother!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> A bounty would help and would be glad if some high rep users offer
>   bounty or answers on my linked question. Waiting for 2 days would be
>   too late and I don't have enough reputation to offer bounty.

There are two problems here:

1. As you stated, you don't have enough rep to offer a bounty, so exactly how long you need to wait to offer a bounty is irrelevant.
2. Allowing bounties immediately after questions are posted would create a sort of arms race, where people with high rep scores could effectively buy more attention for their questions than newer users with smaller scores. That's not helpful. New questions get plenty of attention without a bounty.

Comment: You make good points about wait period. I upvoted your answer. But in this particular case, I think my question is too specific and could be answered by only those who have worked with AVI files before. I am trying to attract attention of the users who might help me. BTW some of my too specific questions before didn't receive enough attention.

Comment: @user2330678 The best way to get good answers is to write a good question. Looking at your linked Q, I can't easily tell what you're asking. A *question* should end with a question mark (?). I can *guess* that you want to know why your file has 0 length, but reading farther it looks like you're asking why no images are being saved to the file. The point is: **Don't make me work to figure out how to help you.** State your question clearly, preferably near the beginning of your post, and then explain how you know what you know and what you've done to try to solve the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am asking two things in that question. I want to know how to fix the length which is always 0 for the generated avi file & I want to know how to open the existing file with image/s & add another image.